# Proving piecewise function convex

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I'm spending a lot of time proving the following function convex. It should be trivial.. would love to have someone point out the obvious.

We have the piecewise function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{if } x \leq 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
For $f(x)$ to be convex, we need to prove:
$$
\lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda)f(x_2) \leq f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2), \forall x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \lambda \in [0,1]
$$

- For $x_1, x2 \leq 0$, we know that the inequality holds, as $f(x)=x^2$ has second derivative 2 for all x, which is sufficient to prove it is convex, and thus  satisfy the inequality.
- If $x_1, x_2 \geq 0$, by a similar argument, the second derivative is 0, and thus it satisfies the inequality.
- The problem comes when I try to prove the inequality to be true for $x_1 \leq 0$ and $x_2 \geq 0$.

  - On LHS, substituting the function into the inequality:
    $$
    \text{LHS} = \lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda)f(x_2) \\
    $$
  - Since $x_2 \geq 0$, we know that $f(x_2) = 0$, thus:
    $$
    \text{LHS} = \lambda f(x_1) = \lambda x_1^2
    $$
  - On RHS, we have:
    $$f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)=\begin{cases}
    (\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)^2 & \text{if } \lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 \leq 0 \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}$$

    - For the second case, it is trivial since $\lambda x_1^2 \geq 0$ must hold for $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
    - For the first case though, we need to prove this inequality holds for $\lambda \in [0,1]$:
      $$\begin{align}
      \lambda x_1^2\geq (\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)^2 &
      \end{align}$$
      ...which I've been struggling with. I should probably be able to incorporate the inequalities $x_1 \leq 0$, $x_2 \geq 0$, and $\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 \leq 0$.

Would appreciate someone to tell me what I'm missing, or if there's a better way to prove this function to be convex. Thanks!

Comment: I would prove this as follows. A function is convex if and only if it's epigraph is convex. The intersection of two convex sets is convex. This function's epigraph is the intersection of the epigraphs of $f(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=0$ which are both convex so we're done.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Unfortunately, the intersection of those epigraphs is the epigraph of $x \mapsto x^2$, not $f$, since $f \ge 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost finished. Regarding what you're struggling with, note that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lambda x_1^2 \geq (\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)^2 \iff \\
(\sqrt{\lambda}x_1)^2 - (\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)^2 \ge 0 \iff \\
(\color{blue}{\sqrt{\lambda}x_1 - (\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)})(\color{green}{\sqrt{\lambda}x_1 + (\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)}) \ge 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

The first factor (i.e., in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$) becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{\lambda}x_1 - (\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2) & = (\sqrt{\lambda} - \lambda)x_1 - (1- \lambda)x_2 \\
& = \sqrt{\lambda}(1 - \sqrt{\lambda})x_1 - (1- \lambda)x_2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $\sqrt{\lambda} \ge 0$, with $\lambda \in [0,1]$ we have $\sqrt{\lambda} \le 1 \; \to \; 1 - \sqrt{\lambda} \ge 0$, and $x_1 \le 0$, we get $\sqrt{\lambda}(1 - \sqrt{\lambda})x_1 \le 0$. Also, $1 - \lambda \ge 0$ and $x_2 \ge 0$, so $- (1- \lambda)x_2 \le 0$. Thus, overall, the value in \eqref{eq2A} (and thus the first factor in \eqref{eq1A}) is $\le 0$.

With the second factor in \eqref{eq1A} (i.e., in $\color{green}{\text{green}}$), since $\sqrt{\lambda}\ge 0$ and $x_1 \le 0$, we have $\sqrt{\lambda}x_1 \le 0$. Also, as you stated, $\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 \le 0$. Thus, overall, this factor is $\le 0$.

Both factors in \eqref{eq1A} are $\le 0$, so their product is $\ge 0$, which means \eqref{eq1A} is true.

---

Since $x_1 \le 0$ and $\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 \le 0$, a bit simpler alternative to \eqref{eq1A} is

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lambda x_1^2 & \geq (\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)^2 \iff \\
\lvert \sqrt{\lambda} x_1 \rvert & \geq \lvert \lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 \rvert \iff \\
-\sqrt{\lambda} x_1 & \geq -(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2) \iff \\
0 & \geq \sqrt{\lambda} x_1 -(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Note the RHS is the first factor (i.e., in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$) of \eqref{eq1A}, so we can proceed as before with \eqref{eq2A}, but without later needing to handle the second factor in \eqref{eq1A} (i.e., in $\color{green}{\text{green}}$).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and ok that is not trivial at all! I'm still digesting how you got to performing the steps in (2). Did you explore the inequalities first, then decided to factor them that way?

Comment: @Trevor You're welcome. Regarding the steps in $(2)$, I realized that since the first term of $\sqrt{\lambda}x_1$ is negative, while the second one of $- (\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)$ is positive, the sign of their sum is unknown. I then noticed that I could combine the two $x_1$ terms and factor out $\sqrt{\lambda}$ to then be able to show each of the two resulting terms in $(2)$ were each $\le 0$, so the overall result is $\le 0$.

Answer (score 4):

It would be simpler to note that $f$ is differentiable (with
$f'(x) = \min (0, 2x)$) and the derivative is non decreasing.

Another approach would be to note that
$\operatorname{epi} f = \{ (x,y) \mid y \ge x^2, x \le 0 \} \cup \{ (x,y) \mid y \ge 0, x > 0 \} $ is convex. It might help to see that
$\operatorname{epi} f = \{ (x,y) \mid y \ge 0, x \ge -\sqrt{y} \}$.

A third approach, albeit a little more technical since it implicitly uses the convex conjugate, would be to note
that
$f(x) = \sup_{y \le 0} xy-{1 \over 4}y^2$, and that the $\sup$ of a collection of convex functions is convex.